# Can I use typeof for enforcing certain string

Tags: typescript

I have a const value:

```
const dataConst = 'constType'
```

And I want to enforce only this value in a certain interface, but this is not possible:

```
interface ExampleInterface {
data: dataConst
}
```

I tried this and it seems to work, but I don't know if it's the best practice:

```
interface ExmapleInterface {
data: typeof dataConst
}
```

I tried and succeeded, but I want to know if what I did is the best practice.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way to do it. I don't think there's much of an alternative.

Comment: It's not clear why you wouldn't just start with `interface ExampleInterface { data: 'constType'; }`, but "best practice" isn't a good fit for SO.

Comment: That's fine, you're using the [`typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator) (which is distinct from the `typeof` JavaScript runtime operator). There has to be a QA that covers this, but I haven't found it (yet).

Comment: What's the actual scenario ? Is this `'constType'` there for debug purposes ?

Comment: FWIW, you'd still need to use explicit type annotations when implementing this interface (see [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggwuaMC8MDkpJQAqAngA4CmOAUFQJZhTkBOAZgsOTAKIAeCAtqQA25AJINmbDjADeVGPCQIAXDChlyIFouRoCVAL41gQhBAgwAssRSnzMWoJH9yDC7wHCxE1u05yFAHpAmFIAVwAjIVpgHRU1DS04vQxsPHQiDRwAbnlQyOjYxGQsXHxoEgocmGD4EHIIMBxYAHcQJgBrGBbaKAALEDDYfs51ChgEMDAQZChacEMgA))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there isn't a good or bad way of doing this. Your example is just one of the many ways of achieving what you want.

Perhaps an explanation of why your example works would be useful.

`const dataConst = 'constType'` assigns an actual value to a `dataConst` constant. You haven't specified the type explicitly for this `const` so the type is inferred by the **TypeScript** compiler. It's smart so it will assign a "string literal" with a value "constType". In contrast, if you were to write something like: `let dataConst = 'constType'`, the type of the `dataConst` would be a simple `string` because the compiler knows that the value can change in the future.

You can't use

```
interface ExampleInterface {
  data: dataConst
}
```

because this is a type definition and only the "types" can go into it. In this case the `dataConst` is the actual value.
In order to "retrieve" the type of the `dataConst` constant we can use `typeof` . Keep in mind this is a different operator from the **Javascript** one with the same name. It can only be used in the context of **Typescript** types.

```
interface ExampleInterface {
  data: typeof dataConst
}
```

So now with that explanation out of the way is there any other way of doing it? Yes. For example:

declaring a type `Value` based on `value` type

```
const value = 'my-constant-value'
type Value = typeof value

interface Example {
  prop: Value
}
```

or declaring `Value` type with a string literal

```
type Value = 'my-constant-value'
const value: Value = 'my-constant-value'

interface Example {
  prop: Value
}
```

or perhaps if you don't need an actual const value and just using the types is sufficient

```
type Value = 'my-constant-value'

interface Example {
  prop: Value
}
```

or even

```
interface Example {
  prop: 'my-constant-value'
}
```

Comment: I would add a `class MyClass implements ExampleInterface` for completeness

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems like this is the best practice